# how to import a file text as a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following file txt:

```
0 1
0 2
0 3
1 637
1 754
```

I need to load it as a list with this format:

```
list = [("0","1"), ("0","2"), ("0","3"), ("1","637"), ("1","754")]
```

how can I do it?
thanks

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  All questions asking for code need to show what the asker has done so far in trying to solve the problem themselves.  Afterwards, we will be more than happy to help with any specific issues you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this,

```
>>> [ (item.split()[0], item.split()[1]) for item in open("your_file.txt").readlines() ]
[('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'), ('1', '637'), ('1', '754')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    print([tuple(line.split()) for line in f])
    [('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'), ('1', '637'), ('1', '754')]
```